# In this case is correct use while instead for?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This is a function that finds the snow level in an array of walls `[5,6,7,12,12,4,11,2]`. The array[i] is the height of the wall and the snow is between two walls. I want to know is it correct to use `while` or should always try to use `for`

```
const findSnowLevel = (walls) => {
    if (walls === undefined) return new Error('No data')

    let snowLevels = new Array(walls.length - 1)

    const fillSnow = () => {
        let i = 0
        while(true) {
            const nextTallerWall = walls.findIndex(v => v > walls[i])
            if (nextTallerWall === -1) break
            snowLevels.splice(i, nextTallerWall - i, ...Array(nextTallerWall - i).fill(walls[i]))
            i = nextTallerWall
        }
        const nextSameWall = walls.lastIndexOf(walls[i])
        snowLevels.splice(i, nextSameWall - i, ...Array(nextSameWall - i).fill(walls[i]))
    }
    //fill the snow since left to right
    fillSnow()

    //invert to fill the snow since right to left
    walls.reverse()
    snowLevels.reverse()
    fillSnow()
    
    //revert and return 
    return snowLevels.reverse()
}
```

Comment: Whether you use `while` or `for` is up to you. There are very small differences in performance that are unlikely to matter with arrays of this size.

Comment: @HereticMonkey In case of LongArrays are this differences significant?

Comment: There is no such object as `LongArray`. If you mean arrays with many elements, yes, the performance becomes more significant. But we're talking on the order of millions of number elements. You'd want to test if it made any significant difference, of course.

Comment: ` while(true) {}` This is an infinite loop!

Comment: @sojin unless you intentionally break out of the loop and the loop can reach that point... somehow. Which I'm pretty sure the code here does